# SSH fails to create a pseudo terminal

Tags: ssh, docker, redhat

Our company's product is an application running in a container. It listens on port 2222 to establish a Command Line Interface.

A customer is having issues with SSH, we have never seen this issue before, and cannot reproduce with the exact same OS (RHEL 7.8), Docker version (RHEL packaged 1.13.1) + Container (our app, same version).

When they do:

`ssh -p 2222 <user>@<ip>`

The errors they see client-side is:

`server refused to allocate pty` or `PTY allocation request failed on channel 0`

The error logs within our app (server) are:

```
openpty: Operation not permitted
session_pty_req: session 0 alloc failed
pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user <>
```

Googling this, a possibility is incorrect permissions on: /dev/pts, or /dev/pts/ptmx, or /dev/ptmx. But they are correct here.

Another possibility is that mount of devpts is missing gid=5. I checked and the mounts look correct both on the host and container.

```
# Host
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
# Container
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=666 0 0
```

I've cross checked my system against the customer's. It all looks to be matching, but obviously something is wrong.

Another data point: Currently they run the container using `docker run --user 100001:0 ...` where user-id=1000001, group-id=0 or root. If instead, they run the container as root `docker run --user 0:0 ...` then this issue does not occur. It's a permissions issue somewhere.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Any hints would be much appreciated as I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Check the audit log.

Comment: @MichaelHampton noted, thanks. I will do a live debug session with customer using strace to attach to ssh process within container. Hopefully that'll pinpoint which system call is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the issue to be the customer's NIS was setting tty to group 7.

We set up strace on the ssh process within the container. When they try to ssh in, openpty() will try to chown and fail, we see this in strace logs:

```
chown("/dev/pts/0", 1000001, 7)         = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

Then when we do `getent group | grep tty` we saw NIS was setting tty to group 7.

This failure will not happen if the container was running as root (--user not specified in docker run), or if docker container is not using host networking.

To fix this, we need to make sure the NIS settings are not leaked into the container, so edit /etc/nsswitch.conf within the container, and remove `nis` for the `passwd`, `shadow`, and `group` entries.

Now when ssh session is launched, /dev/pts/<> in the container will be created with the container group (the "correct" one), and chown should not fail.